# Jekyll: Reverse order lists not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html-lists, jekyll, kramdown

I wrote a blog post ([here](http://lukaspuettmann.com/2017/12/01/favorite-books-2017/)) using Jekyll where I use a reversed order list. So what I want is this:

```
10. Bla bla
9. Bla bla
8. Bla bla
...
1. Bla bla
```

I do this in Jekyll using:

```
---
layout: post
title: 'Title'
---

{: reversed="reversed"}

10. Bla bla
9. Bla bla
...
1. Bla bla
```

Further, in my `_config.yml` I've chosen Kramdown:

```
# Choose Markdown version
markdown: kramdown
```

I host the page on Github Pages.

This displays correctly on Chrome, Safari and Firefox. But on Internet Explorer `(Version: 11.0.9600.18837, Update Versions: 11.0.48)` it's wrong:

[image]

Does somebody have an idea what's going on? Or could I maybe just hardcode the bullet items as "10", "9", ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is going on is what always happens: **Internet Explorer doesn't support it.**

> The reversed property is supported in all major browsers, except
>   Internet Explorer.

[image]

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol#Browser_compatibility

I would rephrase the above like: *The reversed property is supported in all major, serious, standards friendly browsers*.

Answer (score 0):

For other search engines, also consider to put `bibliography_list_attributes` at header of your markdown page:

```
---
title: My list
bibliography_list_attributes:
    reversed: "reversed"
---
```